# Updating and rerendering components in ExtJS 4.2

Tags: extjs

Is there a way to re-render components upon tab switch? I have this data that loads all its store, which contains specific permissions. Each tab must only contain what was provided for their view. See my screenshot below:

[image]

Basically, this loads upon `initComponent`. The dilemma I'm currently having is that the Backoffice tab has a different permission with the Wombat tab. The idea is when either of them contains a permission say an Edit permission (`sCreate`), only that role is allowed to show the edit buttons as seen. So Backoffice has `sEcommCreate` while Wombat has `sCreate`. When either of them satisfies to true, it simply adds/pushes it to the column to be displayed during `initComponent`.

```
if (EcommBackoffice.plugin.Security.getAccess(oMe.sCreatePermission)) {
  aColumns.push({
    header: 'Action',
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    itemId: 'edit-role-btn',
    width: 100,
    sortable: false,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: false,
    menuDisabled: true,
    items: [{
      icon: 'resources/img/editpermissions.png',
      tooltip: 'Edit Permissions',
      scope: oMe
    }],
    editor: {
      xtype: 'text',
      name: 'editRow',
      cls: 'banks-delete-row'
    }
  });

}
```

How do I filter out the display upon switching on the other tab, and also on load? Currently, once `sCreate` or `sEcommCreate` passes its condition, it just adds the buttons on both roles since this is one single `store`.

> Already tried reloading the data store from the controller, but it
>   only loads the data, and not rerender the components to either
>   add/remove/show/hide them.

To be more clear, I need to hide/remove the `Action` column if it has no create permissions assigned to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `actioncolumn` and all actioncolumn items have a function `isDisabled`. I would recommend to use that function to enable/disabled the item, e.g.

```
items: [{
  icon: 'resources/img/editpermissions.png',
  tooltip: 'Edit Permissions',
  isDisabled:function() {
      var isWombatTab = (this.up('tabpanel').getActiveTab().text == 'Wombat');
      if(isWombatTab) return EcommBackoffice.plugin.Security.getAccess(oMe.sCreatePermission)
      else return EcommBackoffice.plugin.Security.getAccess(oMe.sEcommCreatePermission)
  },
  scope: oMe
}],
```

`isDisabled()` will be processed during grid refresh, so whenever you reload the store, the changes should come into effect. To force a refresh without changes to the store, you could of course call `grid.refresh()` from the `activate` event of the tabs.

It should then possible to hide the disabled item via CSS. I don't know exactly what it will take (may also depend e.g. on the theme you use), but a first guess is

```
.x-grid-cell-edit-role-btn .x-item-disabled {
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Tried logging `this.up('tabpanel').getActiveTab().text` and it tells me `Cannot read property 'getActiveTab' of null`.

Comment: Does this also apply to Ext.toolbar? My tabs are created using `Ext.toolbar.Toolbar`. I am assuming `this.up('tabpanel')` is assuming that I am using a tab, right?

Comment: This does not seem to resolve the issue. It does hide the buttons but not the column itself. Also, the behavior stays as it is even when I switch tabs.